# Zookeeper Client Session will be timed-out or be transport to another server?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

As is shown in pic, we have a zookeeper cluster composed by s1, s2 and s3, and two zookeeper client c1 and c2. c1 was connected to s1, and c2 to s3. I wonder what would happen to c2 if a network partition happen to s3, which means s3 can not connect to s1 and s2, but it still running. c2 will recieve an Exception or its session will be migrated to another server?

[image: pic]

[image: split-brain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Zookeeper expert, but also have 3-nodes setup and was reading a lot about and making some experiments with it.

There are [tickTime and syncLimit](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperAdmin.html) settings in Zookepeer, which define how long the followers can be unsynced (If followers fall too far behind a leader, they will be dropped).

I was making an experiment of shutting down the node, to which client was connected. I saw exception in logs and then client reconnected itself to another node.

However there is also a setting `initLimit`, which defines how much time client has to establish connection. If it fails to establish connection within this time, you will get `ConnectionLoss` exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But I think you were a little misunderstanding the question. The network partition problem does not mean server s3 fails. s3 only can not communicate with s1 and s2, but it still running, that is to say, c2 still has the connection to s3.

Comment: @James Yes, that's why I pointed to tickTime and syncLimit parameters. They define how long the node can be unsynced with Leader. Once it wasn't synced with leader for a defined period of time, it will shutdown itself (either your client manages to get all the info it needed in this period of time, or it after node shut downs itself it will reconnect to another node).

Comment: Will correct myself, node of course won't "shutdown itself", but client connection with the node should be dropped and client will try to establish new connection.

Comment: yeah~ I got your point~ thanks! Still can't help to think about what would happen if s3 was the leader. I assume it result the same.